# run a script after docker-compose run (npm)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am an absolute beginner on this.

I need to run two containers, with two separate apps.
One of them should run a script (which runs npm start and not much else), but that might not be possible?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.16.0-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsecret-1-dev groff less bash-completion && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV npm_config_user root
COPY startscript.sh /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startscript.sh
ENTRYPOINT []
```

And the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    first-container:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - '8080:8080' # node web interface
        env_file: .env
        command: bash -c "/usr/local/bin/startscript.sh"

    second-container:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
        - '8181:8181' # node main app web interface

       # volumes:

 volumes:
    node-modules: # persist local node_modules
```

I can run the containers, but the script doesn't run automatically.
Suggestions?

thanks

Comment: One thing I immediately notice is that the indentation is wrong, is your yaml file actually indented this way? The second-container block needs to go inwards.

Comment: no I think I messed up while copying here, but thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just run with `ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]`

And you want to run 2 commands just create a script file `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

npm start &

# Other command here
```

Then `ENTRYPOINT ["/script.sh"]`

Comment: thank you, that would be the entrypoint for both containers though, correct? It might work for me but was wondering how to specify a different one for different containers.. thanks!